# Numbering in latex

Tags: numbering, theorems

I am trying to work on the numbering of the theorems/definitions/lemmas etc., and I have some problems with the numbering.
I want theorems, definitions, examples, etc. to be enumerated among themselves as follows. How can I do that?

```
2. MATERIALS AND METHODS
2.1. CONVEX SETS AND CONVEX CONES
2.1.1. Convex Sets
Definition 2.1.
Definition 2.2.
Lemma 2.1.
Theorem 2.1.
Definition 2.3.
Lemma 2.2
Theorem 2.2
```

Thank you so much.
Best Regards…

Comment: It depends on what packages you are using.  Specifically, one needs to know the names of the counters used.  For example, chapters use `chapter` and sections use `section`, so `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}` will produce 2.1 for the first section of the second chapter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274267/how-can-i-number-theorems-definitions-etc-etc-consecutively-in-latex-without

Comment: Thank you very much for answering and helping. :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.